# How can i join my previously deleted clan?

Tags: guild-of-dungeoneering

I had a clan named "Brutal Bunnies" but accidentally i left the clan and now i can't find it. (which is bookmarked but can't join it.) (#PLYJCCP2)

Any assistance greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: some games have 1 day restriction after you quit a clan / guild before you can rejoin another guild .

Comment: But i deleted the clan yesterday :( .. So by your comment i should make n entry in that

Comment: Are you absolutely certain this question should be tagged [tag:guild-of-dungeoneering]?

Comment: can you please help me in that .. asap ?